# Sql query to check the due date is 3 days away from today?

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL how to check the duedate is 3 days away from today?

For example I have a tax table in which there is field called duedate and i want to find that for which all records the due date is 3 days away from today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `duedate` column is `date datatype` then use [`trunc`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm),

```
select *
from tax
where trunc(sysdate) - trunc(duedate) = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
 select * from tax where trunc(sysdate) - to_date(myDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = 3
```

Comment: @dnoeth:- Removed that!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying a calculation on each and every record (and make indexes unusable) you better do it once:

```
select * from tax 
where myDate >= trunc(sysdate) + 3 
  and myDate <  trunc(sysdate) + 4
```